# What's called 'Universe Data Source' in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

There are several options to choose which data source we want to connect in Crystal Reports including SAP BEx, Relational Connection, and **Universe**. I have difficulties in understanding what exactly do they mean my saying a Universe data source. How are Universe data sources created and where are they used for? What is its difference with relational connection?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Universe Data Connection is for connecting Crystal Reports to a Universe type file(.unv), which are created by a Universe Design Tool by SAP. This file is an abstract layer between the db schema and the user. It gives an opportunity to do queries without knowing the underlying schema of the db, hence can be used by the staff who does not know SQL. 
In contrast Relational Connecting directs to a specific relational database. Both types can have only one connection.